# Print index of XML element

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I would like to write a small utility program which will do the following:

- read a XML file
- for any input argument, print the full path of all the elements matching it

e.g. for the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
    </country>
    <town name="London">
        <year>2014</year>
    </town>
</data>
```

*./myscript year* should give following output:

data.country.1.year

data.country.2.year

data.town.year

Wrote the following script, but not sure how to figure out the index for each element. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from lxml import etree
import sys

tree=etree.parse('file.xml')
tag = '//' + sys.argv[1]
find_text = etree.XPath(tag)
for j in  [tree.getpath(text) for text in find_text(tree)]:
        print j.replace('/','.')[1:]
```

Comment: What is it printing now?

Comment: It prints following:data.country.year

data.country.year

data.town.year

Comment: Sorry! It prints following: data.country[1].year
data.country[2].year
data.town.year
So index is there already. Not sure how I missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be regex.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from lxml import etree
import sys
import re

tree=etree.parse('file.xml')
tag = '//' + sys.argv[1]
find_text = etree.XPath(tag)
for j in  [tree.getpath(text) for text in find_text(tree)]:
    print re.sub(r'[\/\[\]]+', '.', j)[1:] # this will change [ / and ] to a dot.
```

Output:
    data.country.1.year